# how do you display content from custom post type 2 on a single for custom post type 1 that has an ACF relationship?

Tags: custom-post-types

I have an issue that I can't resolve. I'm not a coder and I'm not even an especially logical thinker (thanks dyscalculia) so this is driving me utterly insane.

I am using Breakdance builder and ACF on my site.

Scenario: I have a CPT of Artists and a CPT of Recordings. I've created an ACF relationship between them so that I can create new Recordings and connect them to existing artists (might make it bi-directional, at the moment the field shows on the Artist CPT).

In the Breakdance builder post loop widget, I can select the ACF Relationship field and it ***does*** output only the Recordings associated with the specific Artist whose profile we're on, however...

I cannot change the order in which things appear. It's a completely random output. I have field on the Recording called recording_year_of_release that I want to use so that the Albums are in chronological order but I can't make it do it.

This has been driving me literally insane for a couple of weeks now and as a non-logical, non-coding person I have less than an idea what I'm doing or not doing...

Any help you folks might be able to provide would be greatly appreciated as I'm at the point of smashing my laptop and setting fire to the house so I don't have to think about it anymore!